# Is it possible to be notified each time ffmpeg finish processing one of multiple outputs?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, inotify

I am trying to use a single ffmpeg command to encode a streaming url and generate many output files. In this example, ffmpeg will output three files of duration 5, 10 and 15 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -i <url> \
 -t  5 output_5.wav \
 -t 10 output_10.wav \
 -t 15 output_15.wav \
```

The command works as expected, but I need to know when each one of the output files is available, in order to start further processing as soon as possible.

Is there any way to be notified of each one of the events "file output_XX.wav is ready"?

One approach I have tried is to use inotifywatch to listen for CLOSE events, but I have found that ffmpeg only closes the files when the last one ends.

I could also listen for MODIFY events but there is no way to know when ffmpeg is done, I can only guess it by testing against a hardcoded maximum file size (very nasty solution!).